# Matlab code folding disappears / breaks / disables itself while typing

Tags: matlab, folding

I want to use code folding in my Matlab editor, but folds disappear while typing code. Here is a minimal example:

[image: code folding works]

In the above example I have just folded a for loop and then I start writing the next one. But as soon as I enter "=", the code folding disappears:

[image: code folding disappears]

The folding reappears when I am done with the for loop, but everything is unfolded.

Comment: I would suggest talking to [The MathWorks' technical support](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/index.html) since you're paying for their service and they're far better equipped to handle your issue than SO.

Comment: yea, I'm suffering this too. Just put `end` down first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is just the graphical representation of the problem and the workaround suggested by [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786137/anthony) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765230/matlab-code-folding-disappears-breaks-disables-itself-while-typing#comment74579110_43765230)*.

---

**Problem:**

[image: problem]

**Solution suggested by** [***Anthony***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786137/anthony) **in his** [***comment***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43765230/matlab-code-folding-disappears-breaks-disables-itself-while-typing#comment74579110_43765230)**:**

Putting the `end` first for the loop solves the problem as shown below:

[image: Anthony's Sol]

---

**Random Code used for this:**

```
p=0;
for k=1:10
p=p+k;
end

for l=1:10
p=p+l;
end

for m=1:10
p=p+m;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Matlab support and this is their reply:

> Under certain circumstances, when new code is written in the Editor, previously folded code unfolds.
>   This is a known issue, and the development team is presently working on finding a solution and may address this issue in a future release of MATLAB.

So it seems that at the moment you have to be "careful" how to write your code (as Anthony suggests) in order to avoid breaking the folds.